# Validate uniqueness of a relationship model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an application where users can follow each other. Once this relationship is made a document is added into the collection. That document has two fields `follower` and `followee`. I want to prevent insertions of duplicate relationships. I do not want to query the db, wait for a promise, then insert as this seems like an inefficient approach. I'd rather stop it from saving a new document if the new document's `follower` and `followee` matches an existing document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into creating a [Unique Compound Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-compound-index) index:

```
db.members.createIndex( { follower: 1, followee: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

The created index enforces uniqueness for the combination of `follower` and `followee` values.

> A unique index ensures that the indexed fields do not store duplicate
>   values; i.e. enforces uniqueness for the indexed fields. By default,
>   MongoDB creates a unique index on the _id field during the creation of
>   a collection